# JavaScript Closures example and explanation

Tags: javascript, closures

I have found this example of a closure on codeproject but it does not explain how it works.

```js
    function getMultiplier(multiplyBy){
       function multiply(num){
          return multiplyBy * num;
       }
 
       return multiply;
    }
 
    var multiplyByTwo = getMultiplier(2);
    var multiplyByTen = getMultiplier(10);
    var twoIntoFive = multiplyByTwo(5); 
    var tenIntoSix = multiplyByTen(6);  

    console.log(twoIntoFive); // 10
    console.log(tenIntoSix); // 60
```

Now i am going to assume, with my C brain what is happening. Please correct me or give your explanation.

1. functions in javascript can also be objects, so the inner function multiply(num) is a method of getMultiplier, looking from outside.
2. var multiplyByTwo is assigned the return value of function getMultiplier when invoked with argument 2.
3. when you call getMultiplier(2), javascript interpreter creates an object in memory based on the definition of getMultiplier().
4. that object has a method multiply and it's address is assigned to variable multiplyByTwo.
5. var twoIntoFive = multiplyByTwo(5); calls the getMultiplier(2) object's method multiply(num) with argument 5.
6. that returns simple numeric 10 into variable twoIntoFive
7. multiplyByTwo = 0; will make the garbage collector of javascript delete object getMultiplier(2) from memory.

Comment: Take a look here [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Comment: You can refer to this link to know more about closures.                                         https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: Yes. Just *method* is wrongly used here (and object if its in the sense of js object) @downvoter are you serious??

Comment: @georg unnecessary close. Requesting reopen. The linked question explains how closures work but does not answer op's specific questions.

Comment: @TomM: the dupe appears exhaustive and I doubt there's anything new to say, but let's give it a try!

Comment: @georg thank you, I understand your point and agree that it is pretty much exhaustive in regard of closures. But as I said OP had specific questions regarding his specific piece of code and I doubt that the dupe answers all of these. I did not want to appear rude but in my opinion many questions get closed too fast which makes stackoverflow pretty toxic to new users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting questions.

1. Almost correct, except that on a basic level, in javascript in fact [all functions **are** objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). Also, looking at the latter two variables, `twoIntoFive` and `tenIntoSix`, `multiply()` is a standalone Function in the scope of `getMultiplier()` (meaning it also holds a reference to variables inside that function).
2. Exactly
3. Correct, but keep in mind that it still differs from `getMultiplier`.
4. As explained in [this article](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/#closures), rather than a object, javascript creates an interface with a reference to the already declared variables inside the function.
5. This is how it seems to work. But `twoIntoFive` actually calls the returned interface that references the `getMultiplier()` function parameter
6. Correct.
7. This is correct. Since you removed the reference to the interface, it will be deleted.

**Further Reading**

It's generally a good idea to refer to MDN when having questions about javascript. It's the most complete documentation I have read so far.

- [Closures on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)
- [Stackoverflow question linked by commenter @Yordan Nikolov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)
- [Memory Management (Garbage Collection on MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

*Feel free to correct me or give some feedback if you find errors in my answer or have further questions*

Comment: I was wrong about 3, 4 and 5. because C doesn't have nested functions I presumed that an object of getMultiplier is created on the heap with it's member variables, but that does not give you access to the argument.

Pascal call to a nested function has one additional information in the stack frame of the nested function, that is the pointer to the stack frame of the outer function. 

you need two pointers to call a nested function, they are passed to multiplyByTwo as a return value from getMultiplier(multiplyBy). one for the stack frame of getMultiplier(2) and the other to multiply(num).

Comment: the garbage collector marks that multiplyByTwo has a reference to that stack frame and does not automatically free it upon return from getMultiplier(2). then a call to multiplyByTwo(5) equals multiply(5) passing the pointer to the stack frame of getMultiplier(2).
is this what can be said to be happening here?

Comment: The link doesn't work for me. Yeah the ability to either reference and execute a function while declaring a variable is kind of confusing,

Comment: (...) "then a call to multiplyByTwo(5) equals multiply(5) passing the pointer to the stack frame of getMultiplier(2). is this what can be said to be happening here?"

I'm not sure about this but it seems like it when you run the script in the debugger.

Comment: this explanation of nested functions is the best for understanding closures 
http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/how-nested-functions-work-part-2/228701866

Answer (score 1):

Actually `multiply` is just a function and not a method in terms of OOP.

Basically function are objects, but callable. In this case, it is not a question if a function is an object, but more if you can hand over a reference to a function. This is possible and done with `return multiply`.

After calling `getMultiplier` with a value for the parameter, the value is stored and a function is returned (and assigned).

Then you need to call the function, which reference is stored in `multiplyByTwo`.

The local variable `multiplyBy` is used to return a result. No object is created.

Comment: But multiplyByTwo and multiplyByTen both reference the same function multiply(num), if no objects are created in memory where does multiply(num) get the corresponding value of multiplyBy?
Simply calling a reference of multiply(num) will have multipleBy undefined.

Comment: it generates a new local scope for the variables inside. with returning the function, the scope is saved for it.

Comment: @b'stard - no, they reference different functions. The function (or objects, if you'd like to call them that, which they are) are created and returned every time you call `getMultiplier`. Do this `getMultiplier(2) == getMultiplier(10)` - it's false - they are different objects

Comment: A new local scope for the variables inside based on the definition of getMultiplier(multiplyBy) is some sort of an object in memory.
But where? And what symbol does it use to reference this place in memory? Furthermore it creates two of this in memory. One for multiplyByTwo and one for multiplyByTen. They must be the symbols for the new objects that multiply(num) has access on.
The internal representation of the inner function multiply(num) has to have some hidden pointer to getMultiplier objects, just like C++ functions have the hidden this pointer of the object.

Comment: This might be semantics, but `multiply` doesn't need to know about `getMultiplier` per se, it just needs to know what is available in it's local scope (which happens to be the same as the scope created when `getMultiplier` gets called). The JS runtime obviously keeps track of this scope, but I haven't encountered an engine that provides a mechanism for you to access the scope.

Comment: @Adam - something like that. I use the C term for an object - a data type that occupies real memory location.

Answer (score -1):

Basically a function is a function. I wouldn't say multiply(num) is a getMultiplier's method, it is just declared in its body.

Maybe this way it would be easier to understand?

```
var x = function getMultiplier(multiplyBy){
   var y = function (num){
      return multiplyBy * num;
   }

   return y;
}
```

Anyways. The way it works is: calling getMultiplier returns a function "multiply". The multiply function returns multiplyBy * num, but getMultiplier returns sort of a pre-made multiply function which has multiplyBy already substituted by getMultiplier's parameter.

Thus, when you called getMultiplier(2), what you get under multiplyByTwo variable is:

```
function multiply(num){
   return 2 * num;
}
```

Since getMultiplier(num) simply substitutes a parameter inside returned multiply function, you can pass it literally anything and nothing will be deleted.